# Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try setting setting it manually. Only in Eclipse though

Tags: eclipse, bash, ant, ionic-framework

When I try to run a .sh script in ant, inside eclipse, containing the the code

```
#!/bin/bash
ionic resources android
ionic build android
ionic run android
```

in it I get the error:

```
1mError: Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try setting setting it manually. 
Failed to find 'android' command in your 'PATH'. Try update your 'PATH' to include path to valid SDK directory.
```

But when I run the .sh myself in bash there's no errors. I've set my EXPORTS in .bashrc and in /etc/profile

Here's the ant portion:

```
<target name="prepare-to-build-app" >
    <exec executable="/bin/bash">
        <arg value="call-ionic-commands.sh"/>
    </exec>
</target>
```

What could be the error?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find a solution, but spent a lot time researching things, so maybe this will be useful.

I think the problem fundamentally is that Eclipse is launched without the environmental variable in its context. This could be because its launched with a different user. The directions for setting `ANDROID_HOME` globally depend on your OS.

I looked at the eclipse.ini [docs](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini) and didn't see an intuitive way to launch with an added environmental variable — in this case `ANDROID_HOME`.

I looked at the standard eclipse [ant plugin](https://ant.apache.org/ivy/ivyde/download.html). I was hopping to find an "Environment" tab somewhere in the eclipse run config or **Window >> Preferences**, but had trouble finding the settings for ant in my 
Eclipse version (Neon for Web Development).